# iOS video player Play button disabled after 15 videos

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, video, ionic-framework

I've built an app with Ionic Framework in which I have several videos I want to play. 
To do so I've created a category-like structure from which you can access each different videos, 
by clicking on the video title you navigate to the video player, a simple html page which contains a video tag like

```html
<video controls style="background:#000;width:100%;" playsinline></video>
```

In my video player controller I have the logic that places the right video in the tag that looks like

```js
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $filter) {
            $scope.video = $filter('getById')($rootScope.videos, $stateParams.videoId);
            $scope.videoUrl = 'video/' + $rootScope.category + '/' + $stateParams.videoId + '#t=0';

            $scope.playVideo = function(){
              var vidURL = $scope.videoUrl;
              var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
              myVideo.src = vidURL;
              myVideo.load();
              myVideo.play();
            }
            $scope.playVideo();
       }
```

Basically everything works fine for the first 15 videos played, once I play more then 15 videos the play icon turns to 'barred' like if it was disabled and there is no way to play videos anymore, unless I close the app and open it again.

[image: Play Icon appears disabled]

This is only happening from device, it works perfectly both from browser and iOS simulator

No errors in the xcode errors log are coming up.

It looks like there's a limit of 15 videos that can be loaded by the app in the same view..

I also tried placing the videos into an iframe instead of the video tag like

```html
        <div class="player" style="background: #000; ">
          <iframe src="{{videoUrl}}" width="100%" style="background: #000; position: absolute; height: 100vh" autoplay="0" playsinline></iframe>
        </div>
```

In this case the error doesn't occur but I'm not able to play the video inline (since I cannot insert the playsinline tag in the content of the iframe)

Any idea/suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: UpDate:
tested on a completely new app just generated,
same issue, even with only one video
if you play it 16 times, the 17th time is blocked

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not allow more than 15 video tag, We had same type of issue, to solve this issue you need to clear video reference. Please use below code.

```
$('video').each(function(){
    var vd = $(this)[0];
    vd.pause();
    vd.src="";
    vd.load();
    $(this).remove();
});
```